# In C#, why use Where T : ConcreteClass?

Tags: c#

I came across some code (produced by a code generating wizard - not a person) that looks like this:

```
public class xxxViewModel<T> : SomeBaseClass<T> where T : xxx
```

So xxx is an actual class, and only one specific class too. I'm not sure why the developers would have done that instead of:

```
public xxxViewModel : SomeBaseClass<xxx>
```

The class (xxxViewModel< T >) isn't being used as a generic - it only allows T to be one type of class - xxx, and it doesn't have an enumerators so the actual class type doesn't matter like it would in a List< T >.

What is a reason for defining a generic class where T can only be a specific class?

Comment: I just saw your update. If actual type constraint is not used inside the class then it might be used as compile time constraint for developers to let them know to use only classes inherited from xxx. And somewhere later in code this type can be accessed via reflection lets say.

Comment: Is the type `sealed`?  If not, then there *can* be other types used as the generic argument than just that one type.

Comment: This is probably not relevant to OP, but I have used a similar pattern when writing domain logic messaging code, and letting the IoC find types that have a generic parameter of a sealed concrete class.

Comment: Just remove the constraint and read the compiler error messages.

Comment: Hans, This constraint is added to produce compile time error message. If constraint is removed there will be no compile time error but probably will be runtime one at some point when generic parameter is accessed via reflection.

Comment: @HansPassant The question is asking how generics with the constraints differ from *not using generics at all* and using the constrained type instead of the generic type throughout the class definition, not how generics with a constraint compares to unconstrained generics.

Comment: Has "try it and see what happens" gone out of style?  Such a compiler error message would of course make the question at lot better, enabling *specific* advice why the constraint was necessary.

Comment: There are no compiler errors.

Comment: @HansPassant How would seeing the code not compile when using generics and no generic constraint help the OP understand the difference between using generics with constraints and not using generics at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class SomeBaseClass< T > wants to create a T and return it, so it needs to know the actual type since (in theory) xxx could be xxx or a class based on xxx. eg:

```
class SomeBaseClass<T> {
    public T Create(){ return new T();}
}
```

Without using xxxViewModel< T > then SomeBaseClass.Create would always return a specific class and possibly not the correct T class. However, in this instance, xxx is never inherited - it is effectively, though not actually, sealed.

Any other reasons? Since xxx is never inherited in this case I'm not sure that's the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the class mentioned, any class that inherits from xxx (name as given in your question) are also allowed. So, your constraint now reads as

> type of T can be xxx or any other class derived from xxx

Comment: How does that differ from not using generics? Having "class xxxViewModel : SomeBaseClass<xxx>" still allows xxx to be derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't use multiple inheritance, so the signature:

```
public class xxxViewModel<T> : SomeBaseClass<T> where T : xxx
```

reads:

```
"the generic parameter must implement interface xxx"
```

so you're not tied to a class as the parameter, you're tied to any class that implements that interface.