# Why use "List<T> where T : SomeType" if you know the type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to understand generic constraints. Sadly I've got no reason to use them at the moment but trying my best to come up with situations so I can play with it and understand how/when they will help.

I've run into an issue. To me, these 2 are the same

```
public List<T> Get<T>() where T : DemoClassTwo
public List<DemoClassTwo> Get()
```

Both will return a `List`, and have to be of type `DemoClassTwo` and so I don't see why I'd use the method with that constraint.

Some actual code to demonstrate this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dco = new DemoClassOne();
    dco.Get().ForEach((a) => { Console.WriteLine(a.Id); });
    dco.Get<DemoClassTwo>().ForEach((a) => { Console.WriteLine(a.Id); });
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the supporting classes

```
public class DemoClassOne
{
    public List<T> Get<T>() where T : DemoClassTwo, new()
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        var t = new T();
        t.Id = 1;
        result.Add(t);
        return result;
    }

    public List<DemoClassTwo> Get()
    {
        var result = new List<DemoClassTwo>();
        var d = new DemoClassTwo();
        d.Id = 1;
        result.Add(d);
        return result;    //Code here is pretty much identical to the other Get method
    }
}

public class DemoClassTwo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DemoClassTwo()
    {}
}
```

Have I just found a situation where the 2 *are* the same or am I missing something in the way it works.

This question is similar to [In C#, why use Where T : ConcreteClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867369/in-c-why-use-where-t-concreteclass) but different as I'm not asking why to use it, but why it is different.

Comment: Your generic version accepts `DemoClassTwo` **and any class that inherits from it**, the second one does that also but the first one will return a `List<TypeThatInheritsFromDemoClassTwo>`, whereas the second won't.

Comment: Let's imagine that instead of this toy example the `Get<T>()` method returns records from a database, where the `T` type is mapped to a table. You could then use a single method to access all the tables instead of writing one method per table.

Comment: They aren't the same. The generic method defines a *new* method for every type *derived* from `DemoClassTwo`.

Comment: @Icepickle no they are *not*. The generic method creates one actual method per derived type. The non-generic method only deals with the base type.

Comment: You can use `new T()` to create an instance of the inherited type T. You can create more precise generic collections of type `T`.

Comment: @Icepickle no they are *not*. Try assiging a `List<DemoClassTwo>` to a `List<DemoClassTwoDerivedB>`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, can I not achieve the same thing with an Interface?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions not sure what you mean... You'd need a generic interface I guess ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't see why I'd use the method with that constraint.

Then just don't.

You use generics when you want the same code to operate on different types, and you use constraints when you want to constrain the types you can use with that generic method. That's all there is to it.

Your code knows what it wants to return, namely a `List<DemoClassTwo>`, so it's not really useful to let the caller specify another type using the generic overload.

It might make sense in some scenarios, but you're asking us to make up an example where it does make sense, and that makes no sense.

Given a sensible example, a context where you want to query entities, you could create a filter on a base entitiy:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}

public class NotDeletedFilter<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        return entities.Where(e => e.DeletedOn == null);
    }
}
```

Now you can apply this filter to any queryable entity collection whose entity inherits from `BaseEntity`.

If instead of the class `BaseEntity` you have an interface `IBaseEntity`, you'd better use that.  But sometimes you don't have an existing interface and you can't modify the types to be used with your generic method. In that case you'd have to use a shared base class.

Comment: How is `public IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> entities)` different to `public IQueryable<IEntity> Filter(IQueryable<IEntity> entities)` (note the second is using `I`, not `T`)

Comment: One is using a class, the other an interface... Is your main question about generics, about classes, about interfaces, about generic type constraints using classes or about when to use any of those? In that case I can just say: if you haven't found a use case for either, don't try to shoehorn examples into them but wait until you find a real-life example where you can apply them. Asking random, unrelated questions isn't going to yield a meaningful result.

Comment: `don't try to shoehorn examples into them but wait until you find a real-life example where you can apply them` Yes that is what I'm doing... Your examples are great and I can follow the logic but just struggling to see further than that! I'll keep at it, thanks

Comment: Happy to help, just like I said, I still don't think I understand what difference you're trying to discover.

Comment: It started yesterday when I read http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/18/a-simple-case-for-c-generic-constraints.aspx ... With the example given (which seemed to focus on the `new()` it became very unclear as to the purpose

Answer (score 1):

The two methods are not identical. I think the second without generics is just an example, to show the behavior of the generic one...

Anyway :

```
public List<T> Get<T>() where T : DemoClassTwo, new()
```

means the method expects `T` to be of type (or subtype) `DemoClassTwo`, and having a parameterless public constructor.

```
public List<DemoClassTwo> Get()
```

means the method will return a `List<DemoClassTwo>`.

Imagine you have a class `DemoClassThree`

```
public class DemoClassThree : DemoClassTwo
{
    public DemoClassThree() {
       Console.Write("New instance created !");
    }
}
```

You can then call the generic `Get` method like this, and get a `List<DemoClassThree>`:

```
var demoClassOneInstance = new DemoClassOne()
List<DemoClassThree> result =  demoClassOneInstance.Get<DemoClassThree>()
```

And you will get on your console :

> New instance created !

But If you try to do :

```
public class DemoClassFour
{
    public DemoClassFour() {
       Console.Write("New instance of DemoClassFour created !");
    }
}

List<DemoClassFour> result =  demoClassOneInstance.Get<DemoClassFour>()
```

...you will get a compilation error, because DemoClassFour does not inherit DemoClassTwo.

As Icepickle said, you are only limited by your imagination... or at least real use case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain a Generic Type Parameter to only contain certain `Base Classes` or `Interfaces`. If I extend your example and make some assumptions. `DemoClassTwo` Implies you probably have `DemoClassOne`

Now by extension, you could also have either a `DemoClassBase` or an `IDemoClass`

In this situation, you may want to store any type which implements the `IDemoClass` interface.

With restrictions on the Type a generic can use, you can ensure that a certain subset of functionality on your items may exist, across multiple different implementations of that interface.

Likewise with a `DemoClassBase` You may not care what aother additional methods have been defined on classes that extend `DemoClassBase`, but the code creating an instance of your class using Generic Type Parameters does. Therefore you can specify the `DemoBaseClass` as being something the elements must extend. This ensures the code knows it has access to at least that set of methods defined on the Base Class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the totally best explanation is as [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen) said the

`public List<T> Get<T>() where T : DemoClassTwo`

can return `DemoClassTwo` and every of it`s subclasses, but

`public List<DemoClassTwo> Get()` can return only `DemoClassTwo`